# Como fazer para o array2 ter a mesma relação entre os índices depois do shuffle do array1

Tags: javascript, jquery

> array1 = [1,2,3];
>   array2 = ["um","dois","três"];

array1 e array2 tem uma relação direta entre os índices.

> Embaralhou  array1 -> array1 = [3,1,2];

Como fazer para o array2 ter a mesma relação entre os índices depois do shuffle do array1, para ficar como por exemplo:

> array2 = ["três","um","dois"]?

https://jsfiddle.net/y03d9kjw/

```
    array1 = [1,2,3];
    array2 = ["um","dois","três"];
    //Relação dos arrays entre os índices

    document.write(array1);
    document.write('<br />');
    document.write(array2);


    // embaralhou array1
    array1 = [3,1,2];
    document.write('<br /><br /><br />');
    document.write(array1);


    // Como ficar o array2 = ["três","um","dois"] a partir do embaralhamento do array1;
```

Comment: @Samir encontrei um bug no algoritmo como pode ver: array1 = [1,3,1];
array2 = ["UM",  "três", "um"];// embaralhou array1
array1 = [1, 1, 3]; output -> 1,1,3
um,um,três https://fiddle.jshell.net/r8n5wkkw/ não está funcionando como deveria, eu gostaria de consertar mas eu não consegui nem mesmo entender o que foi feito naqueles foreach com [el] porque não sei o bastante, se puder dá uma olhada novamente por favor grato

Comment: user31050, irei dar uma olhada e assim que puder atualizarei a resposta.

Comment: user31050, estou tendo algum problemas para dar um jeito nesse problema, a curto prazo, vejo que o problema se baseia na ordem dos elementos repetidos, já que se o array1 = [1, 3, 1] for mudado mudado para [1, 1, 3], as possibilidades para o array2 são ["UM", "um", "três"] e ["um", "UM", "três"]. Mas continuarei tentando posteriormente.

Comment: @SamirBraga Esse algoritmo seria para solucionar a ordenação dos dados, dos elementos html, não sei se isso poderia te ajudar, mas nesse meu post mais recente http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143532/alinhamento-para-esquerda-com-detec%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-colis%C3%A3o-de-elementos venho tentando alinhar elementos para a esquerda, usando como referência, a sequencia gerada pelo array ordenado.

Comment: Então para 'realinhar' os dados, nos outros arrays, depois da ordenação, estava usando a função que você fez. Na verdade mesmo, só precisava alinhar os itens para esquerda com detecção de colisão, e a lógica do algoritmo que pensei foi essa de reordenar os dados pelo array, mas talvez você tenha alguma solução melhor para o alinhamento para a esquerda, poderia dar uma olhada no novo post? Fico muito agradecido porque sei que você é uma boa pessoa. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se era assim que desejava:

Primeiramente criei um objeto em que as chaves correspodem ao primeiro array e os respectivos valores correspondem ao segundo array:

```
var corresp = {};
array1.forEach(function(el, i) {
  corresp[el] = array2[i];
});
```

Ficaria algo com isso

```
{
    "1": "um",
    "2": "dois",
    "3": "três"
}
```

E depois de embaralhar o array1, basta refazer o segundo array a partir do objeto

```
// embaralhou array1
array1 = [3, 1, 2];

array1.forEach(function(el, i){
  array2[i] = corresp[el];
})
```

Resultado:

```js
array1 = [1, 2, 3];
array2 = ["um", "dois", "três"];
//Relação dos arrays entre os índices
var corresp = {};
array1.forEach(function(el, i) {
  corresp[el] = array2[i];
})
document.body.innerHTML += (array1);
document.body.innerHTML += ('<br />');
document.body.innerHTML += (array2);

// embaralhou array1
array1 = [3, 1, 2];

array1.forEach(function(el, i) {
  array2[i] = corresp[el];
})
document.body.innerHTML += ('<br /><br /><br />');
document.body.innerHTML += (array1);
document.body.innerHTML += ('<br />');
document.body.innerHTML += (array2);
```

Se preferir uma função:

```js
 function match(array1, array1Sorted, array2) {
   var match = {};
   array1.forEach(function(el, i) {
     match[el] = array2[i];
   })
   array1Sorted.forEach(function(el, i) {
     array2[i] = match[el];
   })
   return array2;
 }

 var ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
 var ar2 = ['um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete'];
 var ar1sorted = [7, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6];


document.body.innerHTML += ar1sorted;
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";
document.body.innerHTML += match(ar1, ar1sorted, ar2);
```